# content of 100vh div display on the next div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've success to make the height of some divs to height:100vh;

But when i try it on a small monitor it seems like the content of the divs get merged 
with the content of the next div .. example :

http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/pvt29848.png

you can try change the white div to height 100vh :
http://attafothman.olympe.in/

( sorry for my bad english )

Comment: Sounds like an overflow issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a element to make it the size of your screen you have to set height and width of the html and body element to 100%, and have a small css reset of all the margins and paddings like this:

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

html, body {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

The element you want to fill the screen width you can simple just give a height of 100%.

Like this:

```
.fitScreen {
   position: relative;
   height: 100vh;
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

Under that you can set any element you want, with any height you want, something like this:

```
.content {
    position: relative;
    height: 1500px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

[Heres a jsFiddle to show you what im doing](http://jsfiddle.net/NXXLK/1/)

Comment: What do you mean by 100vh? can you show us a jsFiddle what you are trying to do? and 100% works right if you can checkout that fiddle of me?

Comment: i'm sure if i do it new in jsfiddle it will works i think ..
check : http://attafothman.olympe.in/
inspect the white part (latest-work) and change height to 100%
it will not be window size ..

Comment: Updated my post, try that?

Comment: Samething nathing changed

Comment: Can you show me a fiddle of what you are trying todo? just paste your code in there. I'll fix it for you.

Comment: I think that the images have to change their size ? when we change the window size too ? because they stay the same width height when i change the window size ..

Comment: Please give me a jsFiddle, lol. I cant tell anything your doing right now. just go to jsFiddle.net and paste your code in there.

Comment: I really dont see the problem, could you please update your post and make it more clear? I really dont know what i have to do with this.

Comment: i need to change .latest-work height to 100% and keep the images inside it even if we change navigator size try it yourself if you can
Change, in the fiddle ive made it's allready .latest-work {
    background: #fff center;
    padding-bottom: 120px;
    height:100%;
}
But as you can see its not fit to the navigator screen !

Comment: check the picture explains every thing :
http://www.shy22.com/upfilpng/pvt29848.png
green strok : content 
red strock : div with height : 100vh

Comment: You know what just tell me what to edit to make the images be small in size when i decrease the navigator size